# Background stretch with content in divs + tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to place a stretched background image that covers the entire window and content in divs and tables.

This code works fine:

> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html>
> <head>
> <title>Background to fit screen</title>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
> <meta http-equiv="Imagetoolbar" content="no">
>
> <style type="text/css">
> /* pushes the page to the full capacity of the viewing area */
> html {height:100%;}
> body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
> /* prepares the background image to full capacity of the viewing area */
> #bg {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
> /* places the content ontop of the background image */
> #content {position:relative; z-index:1;}
> </style>
> </head>
>
> <body>
> <div id="bg"><img src="../images/background.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt=""></div>
> <div id="content">
>
> <table>
> <tr>
> <td>
> <img src="images/1.jpg">
> </td>
> <td>
> <img src="images/2.jpg">
> </td>
> </tr>
> </table>
>
> </div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

The problem is the spacing between images in the cells of the table!
It's pretty bad once you have a very big table with tons of images.

Please help!

Comment: What the hell is IE6?

Answer (score 2):

For your table div, you can rework it and add background-size: 100% 100%;

```
<div id ="bg" style="background-image: url(../image/background.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;">
    <table>
    <!--table stuff-->
    </table>
</div>
```

Obviously you'd want to pull out my inline css into your css file, but this gives you the general idea. With your IE 6 version, since it doesn't support CSS3, you may want to just use a background color instead.

Comment: Hello thanks!
The thing is using background-size the image stretches unproportionally.

The problem now is the spacing between images in the table.

Answer (score 0):

give your table width 100% and give the style to the table

```
#content { background-image:url('image.jpg'); }
```